# Not able to find Day Light Starting Date and End Date in year in android

Tags: java, android

Can anybody tell How to find   Day Light Starting Date and End Date in year in android .I have tried in this way but true will come for all the date.I want to find DST start date and end date inyear

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Denver");
        Date date = new GregorianCalendar (2014, 3, 9).getTime();
        boolean inDs = tz.inDaylightTime (date);
```

Thanks

Comment: Already answered, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449500/get-daylight-saving-transition-dates-for-time-zones-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159023/how-do-i-get-the-date-of-the-start-and-end-of-daylight-savings