# Day light saving time and java

Tags: java, dst

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Daylight Saving Transition Dates For Time Zones in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449500/get-daylight-saving-transition-dates-for-time-zones-in-java)

Is there a way to find the daylight saving time switch day and time for a specified timezone in java ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to utilize: java.util.TimeZone ([reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar thread that gives an answer to your question:

[Get Daylight Saving Transition Dates For Time Zones in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449500/get-daylight-saving-transition-dates-for-time-zones-in-java)

Comment: And this question is a duplicate of that one, or close enough that it should be closed rather than answered.

Comment: You're right.  Should have made it a comment :-X

Comment: I disagree, because the OP specifically asked about solutions using java.util.* and unfortunately jodatime is not in java.util.*

Comment: Where does the OP specify java.util.*?  If they did it has been removed in an edit....

Comment: Ah, okay.  As long as I am not hallucinating :D

Comment: It was gone when I saw it or I wouldn't have marked it as duplicate (or made the comment)!

Answer (score 0):

This information resides in `TimeZone` and is unfortunately not accessible. You can get some of it using `toString()`, but not in a very usable way:

```
for(final String timeZoneId : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()){
    System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId));
}
```

**Output:**

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/GMT+2",offset=-7200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Scoresbysund",offset=-3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=118,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Scoresbysund,offset=-3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Atlantic/Azores",offset=-3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=221,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Atlantic/Azores,offset=-3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Atlantic/Cape_Verde",offset=-3600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null]
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/GMT+1",offset=-3600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Africa/Abidjan",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=3,lastRule=null]
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Africa/Accra",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=17,lastRule=null]
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Africa/Bamako",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=5,lastRule=null]
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Africa/Banjul",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=4,lastRule=null]
```

etc.